# Help with exercise/proof, is is true that W(complement)= span(v(k+1) , ... , v(n))?

Tags: linear-algebra

(exercise 5.2.26 Linear Algebra: A Modern Introduction)

Let {v(1) , ... , v(n)} be an orthogonal basis for R^n
and let  W = span (v(1), ... , v(k)).

Is it necessarily true that W(complement)= span(v(k+1) , ... , v(n)) ? 
Either prove that it is true or find a counterexample.

I tried to prove this with induction, would that be valid? If its not, how else should i do this?

Comment: When you write "W(complement)" do you mean the orthogonal complement or just the set-theoretical complement?

Comment: @Cirdan_00 the orthogonal complement

Answer (score 0):

Remark that $W^\bot$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Indeed, given $u,v \in W^\bot$ and $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$, for all $w \in W$ we have 
$$\langle av+bu,w \rangle = a\langle v,w \rangle + b\langle u,w \rangle=0.$$
Notice also that $W\bigoplus W^\bot=\mathbb{R}^n$. Indeed $W \cap W^\bot =\{0\}$, because  $$w \in W \cap W^\bot \Leftrightarrow \langle w,w \rangle =0 \Leftrightarrow w=0.$$
Hence $\text{dim}(W)=n-k$. Now, obviously $\text{span}(v_{k+1}, \ldots, v_n) \subseteq W^\bot$ and $v_{k+1}, \ldots, v_n$ are linearly independent, so we conclude that they are a basis of $W^\bot.$

Comment: what is that circle with a plus in it ( i think tensor) but i havent learned about that yet

Comment: That's the symbol for direct sum of vector spaces. Do you know what it is?

Comment: what is that? explain, dont assume things you shouldnt assume